# How do the Linked and Related question lists actually work?

Tags: discussion, related-questions, linked-questions

How do the "Linked" and "Related" questions lists actually work on Stack Overflow? How is a post linked or related? Is there any machine learning algorithm used? Or just lexical similarity between the title and body? Or with the help of links provided in the comments and answers?

Comment: And why is 'related' better than search?

Comment: It is linked if it is, um, *linked* to that question. You know, like a regular old link, nothing fancy.

Answer (score 18):

A *linked* question is one with a link to the question you're viewing. The link may be in the question, any of the answers, any of the comments on either the question or its answers, or used as a duplicate target. Links from removed comments and answers also stay in the list, so the source may not be visible to everyone.

Also, this is fully symmetrical: the link may be on either side. So *linked* means either “something somewhere on this page links to this” or “something over at this question links back here”.

The *related* questions are picked by some algorithm, which I think focuses mainly on title and tags.

Answer (score 0):

The "Linked" section of the UI shows posts that were linked by users manually from one page to another in the same site--either by writing that link in a question or answer's body, or in comment text, or by way of duplicate-closure.

The "Related" section of the UI is powered by Elasticsearch, and uses the title and tags of question posts ([source](/questions/423886/?cb=1#comment952273_423895)). There is/was an experiment done to try using Machine Learning (also just using title and tags), where you can read a bit about the implementation [here](/questions/423886/?cb=1#comment952272_423895). See also [How are "related" questions selected?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/20473/997587) (on meta.stackexchange.com).