# Allowing user to see all the dupes that have been marked as duplicate of a given SO post

Tags: feature-request, duplicate-questions

I recently noticed when trying to delete a SO post by clicking on the "Delete" option that a popup appears that says something like:

> This post cannot be deleted as some questions have been marked as duplicates of this.

And then below this message, there is an option to see all the posts that have been marked as a dupe of this particular post.

---

I want that this should be allowed for all posts(and not just posts that can be deleted) and for all users with reputation above a certain number like 10K or whatever is appropriate.

That is, I want that all users with rep > 10K be able to see the posts that have been marked as a dupe of this particular post.

One reason for having this is that many times it happens that when someone asks a question, we have to either google that question to find similar targets or search it in the search bar that pops up when we click on "Close"->"Duplicate", which presents many Stack Overflow posts. But having this(the option that I proposed) can potentially reduce this search time and effort because now the users(with >10K) can go to a similar canonical question and see all the posts that have been marked as a dupe of that canonical post and this can increase chances of finding more accurate dupes in less time for the newly asked question.

---

Most probably this option is already available to moderators but I want that trusted users(with rep above a certain point) can do this too.

---

I am not looking for a SEDE query. Instead, I am looking for a new option to be added to questions, perhaps called "Duplicates", which is shown next to the "Close" and "Delete" options below the question.

---

**Edit**

The duplicate does not answer my question/feature-request as "duplicates" and "linked" are two different/separate things. There may be some overlap between the two but they're not the same. Additionally, my question is about a feature(the popup that pops-up when we click on Delete) to be extended so that there is a separate button perhaps called Duplicates on which if we click we get the same popup and inside that popup there is a list of dupes and **not a** list of linked posts.

Comment: There is a [linked](https://i.stack.imgur.com/A4xeJ.png) section that shows a list of questions. Note that this will also show if you have posted a comment linking to the current question

Comment: You can see the duplicates in the Links section of a question. They aren't distinguished as duplicates (there are also non-duplicate links) but it's at least a place to start.

Comment: That's an interesting request. As power users, we can use SEDE and the API to pull that off, but it would be nice to have natively (although I'd tie it to the CV/RV privilege which is currently at 3K+)

Comment: I am not looking for a SEDE query. Instead i am looking for an option called something like `Duplicates` just right next to options `Close` and `Delete` below a given post.

Comment: What's the point in having a reputation limit for this?

Comment: @DonaldDuck The only reason i mentioned a reputation limit is because currently the popup that pops up when clicking on `Delete` is only for trusted users(users with rep greater than certain value). For example, only users with rep above certain value can can click on `Delete`. That is why i thought if currently there is already a rep limit for `deleting` then there should be a rep limit for seeing duplicates.

Comment: @DonaldDuck it makes sense to tie the feature to a certain privilege level (either CV/RV, 10K tools, or an entirely new level). That said, I'd prefer it not to be reputation-tied too, but oh, well, every privilege right now is tied to reputation...

Comment: I actually think this would be very beneficial even to non-10k users, as a lot of the time the "canonical" question isn't actually that representative of the general case, so it's useful to be able to browse to other questions that were linked to this.

Comment: There's _probably_ a better duplicate target out there but this one answers the question by explaining the feature that already exists to do this

Comment: @TylerH I don't think the duplicate answers my question as "duplicates" and "linked" are two different/separate things. There may be some overlap between the two but they're not the same. Additionally, my question is about a feature(the popup that pops-up when we click on `Delete`) to be extended so that there is a separate button perhaps called `Duplicates` on which if we click we get the same popup and inside that popup there is a list of dupes and **not a list of linked posts**.

Comment: I don't think such a feature is likely to be implemented since you can literally find out the same information by looking at the linked list. You can easily discern which questions in the linked list are duplicates because the titles of those questions will have "[duplicate]" on the end. Further, this feature seems like it would only serve to make it easier for users to delete posts which are used as duplicate targets, which in the aggregate is probably not a good thing, and even in cases where it might be, still results in fewer questions, which the company doesn't seem to want to encourage.

Comment: I'm not sure to completely understand the use case.  You want this so that when searching for a dupe to a new question you can go from the honeypot canonical to a more specific question? IIRC not everybody is able to access closed questions and by linking them to such an already closed question they'll get redirected automagically to the honeypot anyway. I don't remember the threshold for this rule, either a low rep, or even maybe just the need for an account, but anyway I think that represents a large majority of SO readers.

Answer (score 2):

This feature already exists (as the [duplicate target](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/261963/how-do-the-linked-and-related-question-lists-actually-work) that once adorned the top of your question showed).

A "Linked" list will appear in the right-hand side bar of a question ("A") if any other questions ("B" and "C") on the site link to it, including if question "A" is used as a duplicate target for questions "B" and "C".

It's true that links/mentions of the question *in passing* (e.g. in a comment or in the body of a post) will also get a question added to the "Linked" list. However, you can *easily* discern which questions (of e.g. "B" and "C") on the list are likely to be closed as duplicates of question "A", because the titles of such questions on the list will have "[Duplicate]" appended to them.

So it is unlikely devs will build a feature that does not add anything particularly novel, and that has no particular utility even if it *did* exist.

Comment: No the duplicate target was not accurate. "Duplicates" and "Linked" are different things. There may be a large overlap between the two but closing this as a dupe of [this](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/261963/how-do-the-linked-and-related-question-lists-actually-work) was wrong. I am asking for an already existing feature(the popup that pop-ups when we click on `Delete`) to be **extended** so that we can just click on a button perhaps called `"Duplicates"` just on the right side of `Close` and `Delete` below the post. Note, i agree that the "Linked" list is still very useful.

Comment: As my answer mentions, you haven't provided any reason this new feature is needed that isn't already covered completely by the existing feature that provides this functionality. Your question states "we have to google to find what duplicates exist" and the existing Linked Questions feature obviates the need to google already; 100% of the non-deleted questions that link to the one you're viewing are guaranteed to appear on that list.

Comment: For one, linked question can be anything that mentions a link to the question, which is very general and not what i am looking for. For example, i may just copy/paste a poorly(somewhat) related SO post's link to some other SO post and then then that poorly added post will automatically be added into the linked list. This makes the linked list unnecessarily huge and not 100% accurate. The "duplicates" on the other hand will be directly related to the post.

Comment: Did you miss the part where I said "*the titles of such questions on the list will have "[Duplicate]" appended to them*"? Have you used this feature before? You should check it out to see what I mean. See for example how clearly delineated the duplicate questions are: https://i.stack.imgur.com/XQrnm.png

Comment: My point is i don't want to look for the *"[Duplicate]"* appended to the titles. I just want a list of posts that have been marked as duplicate of this particular post. Note also that "linked" list are symmetrical which is not what i am asking in my question. That is why i said, "duplicates" and "linked" are different. Again i am not saying the linked list is not useful. It is useful but it is a) symmetrical b) we have to visually select by reading the title to find if the *"[Duplicate]"* is appended to that title.

Comment: Or an option to filter "linked" to 1. exclude questions that aren't duplicates, and 2. exclude linked questions that are duplicates of questions other than this

Comment: @AnoopRana I understand your point, I just think that infinitesimally small amount effort is, well, expected. The feature here is handing you what you want on a big ceramic tray, and you're complaining that you want it on a silver platter instead.

Comment: @TylerH It's good that we have a workaround available using the "linked" list option here but i am not asking something entirely new here. The popup tray that i am asking for already exists when we try to delete some post and that post has some duplicated linked to it. I am asking for extending that feature so that now we can just directly access that popup tray using a button perhaps called "Duplicates". Also, note it looks like an infinitesimally small amount of effort but when i do it regularly(on a regular basis) it just becomes a big effort.